# Load variables in a view, then use them from a component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js project where I get a bunch of values from the backend via REST calls. One of these variables tells me if the user has verified his email address or not. The values are loaded at `mounted` of the main page. I want to pass the Boolean value `verified` to a component that shows a toast reminding the user to verify his email if not verified. I don't want to submit the REST call twice (from the main page and the component). is there a way to pass that value from the page to the component?

My Application has many pages, so instead of adding the component on top of all pages, I added it in the `App.vue` like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="app">
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <b-container fluid class="app-body">
      <div class="main">
        <My-email-verification-component></My-email-verification-component>
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </b-container>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

If I had the component added to each and every page, it would have been easy to use a prop from the main page.
Now I think I should consider the way I'm doing this.. seems like a bad practice. is it?

Comment: I would suggest reading offical Vue documentation about props and passing props to other components https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: Event bus is another option, though overkill for a single use case - https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [technically possible](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2k8ov78w5?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue) to pass data to the current component in view by binding the data to props on the `<router-view>`:

```
<my-email-verification v-model="verified" />
<router-view :verified="verified" />
```

This requires that the email verification component [support `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) by accepting a `value` prop and emitting new values with an `input` event:

```
// MyEmailVerification.vue
export default {
   props: ['value'],
   mounted() {
      const isVerified = /* ... */
      this.$emit('input', isVerified)
   }
}
```

> seems like a bad practice. is it?

**Opinion:** No, I think it's good practice to stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). However, I personally prefer using components only to render something. For your use case, I would move the email verification into a utility class, import it into `App.vue`, invoke it as needed (e.g., `mounted()`), and store the result in a local data property (`isVerified`).